# Tmux keybinding to swap pane left or right

Tags: tmux

I'm aware that `:swap-pane -U` and `:swap-pane -D` will swap panes up or down, but I'd like a keybinding to swap panes left and right.

The only way I can think of to do this would be to first determine the pane index of the current pane, then run `:select-pane -R` or `-L` and determine its index, and finally run `:swap-pane -s (first pane index) -t (second pane index)`.

I'm just not sure how to do this in `.tmux.conf` - is it possible to have subcommands which return something within another command?

For example, something like this:

`bind-key -n C-{ swap-pane -s **get current pane ID** -t **get pane ID of 'select-pane -L'**`

`bind-key -n C-} swap-pane -s **get current pane ID** -t **get pane ID of 'select-pane -R'**`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`:bind-key -n C-{ select-pane -L \; swap-pane -s '!'`

This should tell tmux to select the left pane, and then swap with the previously active pane.

Also, `swap-pane -s {right-of}` seems to work.
Here is the list of ways to refer to other panes:

```
{last} !       The last (previously active) pane
{next} +       The next pane by number
{previous} -   The previous pane by number
{top}          The top pane
{bottom}       The bottom pane
{left}         The leftmost pane
{right}        The rightmost pane
{top-left}     The top-left pane
{top-right}    The top-right pane
{bottom-left}  The bottom-left pane
{bottom-right} The bottom-right pane
{up-of}        The pane above the active pane
{down-of}      The pane below the active pane
{left-of}      The pane to the left of the active pane
{right-of}     The pane to the right of the active pane
```

See the [online man page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#COMMANDS) for reference.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea that you could reference those variables, that's super useful. I'll award the bounty as soon as it allows me to, thanks! I was referring to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) man page which I guess is probably outdated because my local tmux manpage lists these variables while that one doesn't.

Comment: Great!  [this](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) is the man page I used.  also has similar info for "windows" in addition to "panes".

Comment: Those variables are a god-send. How come so few answers and tutorials mention them, I wish I knew about this earlier.

Comment: it should be `swap-pane -s '{right-of}'`

Answer (score 3):

One can also add following line to `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind v swap-pane -s '!' -t $TMUX_PANE
```

This will interchange current pane with the last visited pane. Consecutively go to the two panes needed to be interchanged and use `<prefix>v` (above command) to perform the swap. Note that `<prefix>q` shows the id of the panes. The additional advantage is that the swapping also works across different windows.

Comment: Very clean :+1: